# Paypal Adaptive Payments Plugin Not Working with WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, paypal, woocommerce, paypal-adaptive-payments

I have a wordpress ecommerce site, selling online ebooks and guides. I installed this plugin:
https://www.woothemes.com/products/paypal-adaptive-payments

I want to use it to send commissions automatically from the primary paypal account, to a 2nd account.

It worked for about 1 day, then for some reason now won't work. Everytime I click on "Proceed to Paypal" to make the payment, I get this error at the top of the page:

"An error has occurred while processing your payment, please try again. Or contact us for assistance."

I followed all documentation to the bone, and I know my API credentials are correct, the API was approved and is Live.

Any help please?

Comment: You should contact WooThemes for support.

Comment: I did. They were unable to help and were not sure why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue.  My site has SSL.

Woothemes Support is very limited and takes days to respond.

Their latest response was to make sure I am using the latest version 1.1.5, but from what I gather, that version isn't even available at this time. So the ball is back in Woothemes court & expect another couple days for a response.

Right now, I have PayPal working on it. I called in and they said they put in an "integration" ticket with their developers who will reach out to me to fix it.

So they're in the process of working it out, with my fingers crossed.  It's likely best to call in to PayPal.
Best of luck!

Comment: Nice answer, but try to separate in paragraphs to facilitate readability.

Comment: Did you ever figure out the issue? I am running into the same problem.